# AWS ECS getting error while pulling images from ECR "ResourceInitializationError: unable to pull secrets or registry auth: "

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate, aws-nat-gateway

I was creating an ECS environment for PHP Larval with 2 services one is hosted in a public zone and another in a private zone with nat gateways. To save some cost I have removed the nat gateways and moved the other docker to the public subnet. Now I am unable to pull the container images.

I am tried assigning the public IP to container still unable to pull the images.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check whether you have any Security Group rules or ACLs blocking communication?

Make sure that Internet Gateway is associated with the public subnet and that there is a route in the subnet route table.

Also, look at the IAM roles associated with your ECS tasks. If you're using ECR, the task execution IAM role should have the `AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly` policy attached.

If using a private registry, ensure you have provided the correct authentication details.